# Can you allow push notifications in the app programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I use push notifications in my app and as its expected the user sees a dialog box asking to allow the push notifications when the app starts.  The logic of my app depends on receiving push notifications and if the user didn't allow the push notification by mistake or not knowing how the application works, the app won't work correctly.  Is there a way to allow push notifications in the app programmatically even if the user doesn't allow it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do like this.Before iOS 8 You can detect the APNS state use

```
UIRemoteNotificationType enabledTypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
```

or after iOS 8:

```
UIRemoteNotificationType enableType = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
```

or Swift:

```
let remoteState = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()
```

You can prompt users if they close APNS or launch the App .Such as: You have closed the APNS and you will lose some important message.Please go to Settings -> Notifications -> App to enable APNS

or you can jump to your app page after iOS8 :

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
   BOOL canOpenSettings = (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL);
        if (canOpenSettings) {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
            }}
```

Answer (score 3):

No. If the user says you can't sent them push notifications, you can't send them push notifications. Apps don't get to ignore the user's choice there.

However if you're sending **silent** push notifications-- those that get delivered to your app but not displayed to the user-- you don't need to get permission. If that suits your needs, great, but you don't get to have user-visible pushes without permission.

Comment: I do have notifications that are silent and ones that aren't.  It is the silent one that I am concerned about.  In my case the user didn't allow the notifications and the app didn't get the silent notifications either.  Is there a way to distinguish between the two and let the silent notifications delivered to the app even when the user rejects presumably the visible one?  Thanks!